# Execute var python

Tags: python, execute

I've got the below def, ITEM comes from a menu.  I'm having problems with encoding hex though, as the format of the command is different i.e. var then command.  How can I have bottomtext.insert(INSERT, var + process) execute please?  At the moment all that happens is that testingtext.encode("hex") is inserted into bottomtext.  I did look at exec but there seems to be a general view that exec shouldn't be necessary?  Base64 + url encoding work fine.  Any assistance please?

Thank you

```
def gui(item):
    def default_encode(s):
        s.encode('oops')
        print s.encode

    encodehexstring = '.encode("hex")'
    mapping = {"encode_b64": base64.encodestring,"encode_url": urllib.quote_plus,"encode_hex": encodehexstring}
    process = mapping.get(item, default_encode)

    def getText():
    #clear right text field
        bottomtext.delete(1.0, END)
    #var equals whats in left
        var = middletext.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
    #encode it

    #insert encoded var in right
        if process == encodehexstring:
            bottomtext.insert(INSERT, var + process)
        else:
            bottomtext.insert(INSERT, process(var))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapping = {'encode_b64': base64.encodestring, 'encode_url': urllib.quote_plus, 'encode_hex': lambda s: s.encode('hex')}
```

Edit:
Or without the lambda (means exactly the same, it's just more to write):

```
def hexencode(s):
   return s.encode("hex")
mapping = {'encode_b64': base64.encodestring, 'encode_url': urllib.quote_plus, 'encode_hex': hexencode}
```

Comment: since the person asking the question is obviously a beginner, I would (and did, in another question) recommend a simple function rather than lambda. Lambdas can be pretty confusing to people just learning to program.

Comment: Actually I'm having problems with lambda now - for example on the menu I'd like to add decode functions.  I can't have two lambda's can I?  Thanks

Comment: By two lambda's sorry I mean having an encode and decode hex function....

Comment: user1517644: I don't know what you mean. Wouldn't you have another entry in the menu for the decode function? Otherwise, if you clicked the single menu entry, how would it know whether to encode or decode?

So your "mapping" variable would just contain twice as many entries, like {"encode_b64": ..., "decode_b64": ...}

Comment: @user1517644: there is no limit to how many lambdas you can use. I recommend writing your own functions until you get a bit more experience. It's a simpler, more straight-forward solution.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for replies.  Tried as per previous s.encode and see the following from terminal when running the script.  Had an error stating s not being globally defined?
mapping = {"encode_b64": base64.encodestring,"encode_url": urllib.quote_plus,"encode_hex": s.encode("hex"), "decode_b64": base64.decodestring, "decode_url": urllib.unquote_plus, "decode_hex": s.decode("hex")}
NameError: global name 's' is not defined

Comment: obviously i've tried global s directly beneath the def gui(item): - thanks